# SocketException: ErrorCode vs. SocketErrorCode

Tags: c#, sockets, error-handling

Is ErrorCode and SocketErrorCode always the same value but represented as different types?

The [SocketException class description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets.SocketException%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives them mostly identical descriptions, but I don't see any explicit note that they are the same value.

SocketErrorCode seems more useful, since it is an enumeration you can make more beautiful code like:

```
if(se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted)
```

rather than:

```
if (se.ErrorCode != 10004)
```

or

```
if (se.ErrorCode != (int)SocketError.Interrupted)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are exactly the same.

Looking at [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/SocketException.cs#feed9e8ed7f20227):

```
public override int ErrorCode {
    //
    // the base class returns the HResult with this property
    // we need the Win32 Error Code, hence the override.
    //
    get {
        return NativeErrorCode;
    }
}

public SocketError SocketErrorCode {
    //
    // the base class returns the HResult with this property
    // we need the Win32 Error Code, hence the override.
    //
    get {
        return (SocketError)NativeErrorCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's that conversion there every time you call SocketErrorCode, but one would hope you're not getting errors in a performance sensitive context.